# Escaping ampersands in Blaze Html

Tags: haskell, blaze-html

I want to put an HTML entity (in particular, `&copy;`) into my document.  However if I type it and feed it as a `Text` straight into a blaze combinator, the ampersand is html-escaped and comes out as literally `&copy;` -- or rather, the HTML outputted is `&amp;copy;`, which is kind of ironic.

(If I use `blaze-from-html` on HTML that contains `&copy;`, `blaze-from-html` turns it into the unicode copyright symbol "`©`", which works, but I'd still like to know if it was possible to access the lower-level HTML with blaze and type a literal html-source `&`.)

Comment: have you tried the number code?

Comment: @DiegoNolan if you mean using the numberical HTML entity `&#169;`, yeah, i've tried it, and blaze does the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the blaze `Text.Blaze.Html.toHtml` function, there is a corresponding `preEscapedToHtml` function that will *not* escape entities. Sample ghci session -

```
λ> renderHtml $ toHtml "&copy;"
"&amp;copy;"
λ> renderHtml $ preEscapedToHtml "&copy;"
"&copy;"
```